# Controlling a Checkbox group input type with a Radio button input type in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core, webapi

In my Visual Studio 2019 ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC project, I wish to consume a publicly available Joke API
at [information about a Joke API](https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/?ref=apilist.fun#info) 
which is a [try out form for a joke api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASiPq.png).
Now I am stuck at the implementation of catergory/categories at the top of this form where the functionalities I want to implement are as follows:

**Case 1:**
[In the image for category/categories the state of radio and checkboxes are shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqEFI.png)

Here if you enable custom radio button and two of the checkboxes (corresponding to this radio, say Programming and Misc that are controlled by it as shown
then the request URL becomes like the following image: (Ignoring all other filters in the UI)
[Custom radio enabled with Programming and Misc check boxes checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBouG.png)

**Case 2:**
[Here the Any radio button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TXpJ.png) which unclicks the Custom radio button and disables all of its check boxes and the resultant request URL is as shown below
[Request URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSPae.png)

My View for the getrequestURL action method so far is:

```
@model WebAPIConsume.ViewModels.JokeRequestURLVM
```

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="GetRequestURL" asp-controller="Jokes">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="category" class="control-label"> Select category/categories</label>
        @*<input type="radio" value="Any" /> Any
        <input type="radio" value="Custom" name="Custom" /> Custom:*@
    <div><input type="radio" name="category" value="Any" class="control-label" checked="checked" /> Any</div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="Custom" class="control-label" /> Custom:
        <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" value="Programming" class="control-label" /> Programming
        <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" value="Misc" class="control-label" /> Misc
        <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" value="Dark" class="control-label" /> Dark
        <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" value="Pun" class="control-label" /> Pun
        <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" value="Spooky" class="control-label" /> Spooky
        <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" value="Christmas" class="control-label" /> Christmas
    </div>  
</form>
```

```
JokesController code:
[HttpGet]
        public  IActionResult  GetRequestURL()
        {

          return View();
        }

View Model:
public class JokeRequestURLVM
    {
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string language { get; set; }
        public string format { get; set; }
        public Joke joke { get; set; }
        public Flags flags  { get; set; }
        public int amount   { get; set; }
    }
Models:
Joke:
public class Joke
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string joke { get; set; }
        public string setup { get; set; }
        public string delivery { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public Flags flags { get; set; }
    }

public class Flags
    {
        public bool nsfw { get; set; }
        public bool religious { get; set; }
        public bool political { get; set; }
        public bool racist { get; set; }
        public bool sexist { get; set; }
    }
```

Finally, after having achieved the objective as in the problem description, how do I use the values of the checked radio button (Any) or (Custom) radio button along with its group of checked checkboxes say Programming and Misc so that the resulting string for the request looks like below:
[Request URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKfzu.png)

I want this request URI passed as a string to the GetRequestURL() action method in Jokes Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update 2/9/2021

You could get `Categories` like below.

```
    [Route("~/Jokes/GetRequestURl/{categories}")]
    public IActionResult GetRequestURl(string Categories)
    {
       string[] CategoryList = Categories.Split(',');
       return Json(CategoryList);
    }
```

Test result:
[image]

---

Update 2/8/2021

Already updated with `buildURL()` from the [Javascript file](https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/static/index.js) of JokeAPI.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>
        var settings = {
            baseURL: "https://127.0.0.1",
            Endpoint: "Jokes/GetRequestURL",
            anyCategoryName: "Any",
        };

        window.onload = function () { reRender(); };

        function reRender() {

            var isValid = false;
            document.getElementsByName("category").forEach(function (el) {
                if (!el.checked)
                    return;

                if (el.value == "Any") {
                    isValid = true;
                    ["cat-cb1", "cat-cb2", "cat-cb3", "cat-cb4", "cat-cb5", "cat-cb6"].forEach(function (cat) {
                        document.getElementById(cat).disabled = true;
                    });
                }
                else {
                    var isChecked = false;
                    ["cat-cb1", "cat-cb2", "cat-cb3", "cat-cb4", "cat-cb5", "cat-cb6"].forEach(function (cat) {
                        var cel = document.getElementById(cat);
                        cel.disabled = false;

                        if (cel.checked)
                            isChecked = true;
                    });

                    if (isChecked)
                        isValid = true;
                }
            });


           buildURL();

        }

        //#MARKER build URL
        function buildURL()
        {
            var queryParams = [];

            //#SECTION categories
            var selectedCategories = [settings.anyCategoryName];
            if(document.getElementById("Custom").checked)
            {
                selectedCategories = [];
                if(document.getElementById("cat-cb1").checked)
                {
                    selectedCategories.push("Programming");
                }
                if(document.getElementById("cat-cb2").checked)
                {
                    selectedCategories.push("Miscellaneous");
                }
                if(document.getElementById("cat-cb3").checked)
                {
                    selectedCategories.push("Dark");
                }
                if(document.getElementById("cat-cb4").checked)
                {
                    selectedCategories.push("Pun");
                }
                if(document.getElementById("cat-cb5").checked)
                {
                    selectedCategories.push("Spooky");
                }
                if(document.getElementById("cat-cb6").checked)
                {
                    selectedCategories.push("Christmas");
                }

                if(selectedCategories.length == 0)
                {
                    selectedCategories.push(settings.anyCategoryName);
                }
            }

            tryItURL = settings.baseURL + "/" + settings.Endpoint + "/" + selectedCategories.join(",");

            if(queryParams.length > 0)
            {
                tryItURL += "?" + queryParams.join("&");
            }

            document.getElementById("urlBuilderUrl").innerText = tryItURL;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="GetRequestURL" asp-controller="Jokes">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="category" class="control-label"> Select category/categories</label>
            @*<input type="radio" value="Any" /> Any
            <input type="radio" value="Custom" name="Custom" /> Custom:*@

            <div><input type="radio" name="category" value="Any" checked="checked" id="Any" class="control-label" checked="checked" onchange="reRender()" /> Any</div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="category" value="Custom" class="control-label" id="Custom" onchange="reRender()" /> Custom:
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb1" value="Programming" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Programming
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb2" value="Misc" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Misc
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb3" value="Dark" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Dark
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb4" value="Pun" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Pun
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb5" value="Spooky" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Spooky
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb6" value="Christmas" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Christmas
            </div>
            <span id="urlBuilderUrl">/Jokes/GetRequestURL</span>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Test result:

[image]

---

You could use JavaScript to control.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () { reRender(); };

        function reRender() {

            var isValid = false;
            document.getElementsByName("category").forEach(function (el) {
                if (!el.checked)
                    return;

                if (el.value == "Any") {
                    isValid = true;
                    ["cat-cb1", "cat-cb2", "cat-cb3", "cat-cb4", "cat-cb5", "cat-cb6"].forEach(function (cat) {
                        document.getElementById(cat).disabled = true;
                    });
                }
                else {
                    var isChecked = false;
                    ["cat-cb1", "cat-cb2", "cat-cb3", "cat-cb4", "cat-cb5", "cat-cb6"].forEach(function (cat) {
                        var cel = document.getElementById(cat);
                        cel.disabled = false;

                        if (cel.checked)
                            isChecked = true;
                    });

                    if (isChecked)
                        isValid = true;
                }
            });

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="GetRequestURL" asp-controller="Jokes">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="category" class="control-label"> Select category/categories</label>
            @*<input type="radio" value="Any" /> Any
            <input type="radio" value="Custom" name="Custom" /> Custom:*@

            <div><input type="radio" name="category" value="Any" checked="checked" id="Any" class="control-label" checked="checked" onchange="reRender()" /> Any</div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="category" value="Custom" class="control-label" id="Custom" onchange="reRender()" /> Custom:
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb1" value="Programming" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Programming
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb2" value="Misc" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Misc
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb3" value="Dark" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Dark
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb4" value="Pun" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Pun
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb5" value="Spooky" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Spooky
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb6" value="Christmas" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Christmas
            </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: I have edited my question a bit to ask how it could use the checked values in the controller action method.

Comment: Post parameters to your controller action method.

Comment: Hi @Michael Wang thanks for your solution. Can you let me know the best way to post parameters to the controller action method in this case?

Comment: @krchome I post the codes of action method.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have also been able to solve it by calling Ajax in BuildURL function and then creating another HTTPPost method GetRequestURL that accept the string URL passed to it from the ajax call. I can then use this URL string to communicate with the Joke API.

Comment: Your latest code for getting the categories passed to the action method doesn't work with the actual solution in VS. It needs to be passed as I said through the Ajax calls. Nevertheless thanks a lot for helping me this far.

Comment: Hi there @Michael Wang, I have put another new question as a follow up at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66146220/unable-to-render-the-response-from-the-joke-api-server-to-the-view-asp-net-core   Will appreciate your reply