# Unable to render the response from the Joke API server to the view ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-webapi

This is a follow-up question to my earlier question [Controlling a Checkbox group input type with a Radio button input type in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66041616/controlling-a-checkbox-group-input-type-with-a-radio-button-input-type-in-asp-ne) for which I accepted the solution.

I am unable to get the view to render the response from the Joke API server, even though I can see the response on setting a breakpoint on the view code.

Model:

```
public class Joke
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string joke { get; set; }
    public string setup { get; set; }
    public string delivery { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Flags flags { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public class JokesController: Controller
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetRequestURL()
        {
            return View();
        }
        

        [HttpPost]
        public  async Task<IActionResult> GetRequestURL(string newData)
        {
            string receivedData = newData;
            List<Joke> randomJoke = new List<Joke>();

           
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(receivedData))
                {
                    string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    randomJoke = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Joke>>(apiResponse);
                }
            }
            return View(randomJoke);

           
        }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Joke>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        var settings = {

            baseURL: "https://v2.jokeapi.dev",
            Endpoint: "joke",
            anyCategoryName: "Any",
        };
        var tryItURL = "";
        window.onload = function () { reRender(); };

        function reRender() {

            var isValid = false;
            document.getElementsByName("category").forEach(function (el) {
                if (!el.checked)
                    return;

                if (el.value == "Any") {
                    isValid = true;
                    ["cat-cb1", "cat-cb2", "cat-cb3", "cat-cb4", "cat-cb5", "cat-cb6"].forEach(function (cat) {
                        document.getElementById(cat).disabled = true;
                    });
                }
                else {
                    var isChecked = false;
                    ["cat-cb1", "cat-cb2", "cat-cb3", "cat-cb4", "cat-cb5", "cat-cb6"].forEach(function (cat) {
                        var cel = document.getElementById(cat);
                        cel.disabled = false;

                        if (cel.checked)
                            isChecked = true;
                    });

                    if (isChecked)
                        isValid = true;
                }
            });


            buildURL();

        }

        //#MARKER build URL
        function buildURL() {
            var queryParams = [];

            //#SECTION categories
            var selectedCategories = [settings.anyCategoryName];
            if (document.getElementById("Custom").checked) {
                selectedCategories = [];
                if (document.getElementById("cat-cb1").checked) {
                    selectedCategories.push("Programming");
                }
                if (document.getElementById("cat-cb2").checked) {
                    selectedCategories.push("Miscellaneous");
                }
                if (document.getElementById("cat-cb3").checked) {
                    selectedCategories.push("Dark");
                }
                if (document.getElementById("cat-cb4").checked) {
                    selectedCategories.push("Pun");
                }
                if (document.getElementById("cat-cb5").checked) {
                    selectedCategories.push("Spooky");
                }
                if (document.getElementById("cat-cb6").checked) {
                    selectedCategories.push("Christmas");
                }

                if (selectedCategories.length == 0) {
                    selectedCategories.push(settings.anyCategoryName);
                }
            }

            tryItURL = settings.baseURL + "/" + settings.Endpoint + "/" + selectedCategories.join(",");
           // tryItURL =  selectedCategories.join(",");
            if (queryParams.length > 0) {
                tryItURL += "?" + queryParams.join("&");
            }


            document.getElementById("urlBuilderUrl").innerText = tryItURL;

              $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetRequestURL")",


                  data: { newData: tryItURL },
                  dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Success");
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                console.log("Failed");
            }
        });
        }
       // var testString = settings.baseURL + "/" + settings.Endpoint + "/" + selectedCategories.join(",");


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="GetRequestURL" asp-controller="Jokes">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="category" class="control-label"> Select category/categories</label>
            @*<input type="radio" value="Any" /> Any
        <input type="radio" value="Custom" name="Custom" /> Custom:*@

            <div><input type="radio" name="category" value="Any" checked="checked" id="Any" class="control-label" checked="checked" onchange="reRender()" /> Any</div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="category" value="Custom" class="control-label" id="Custom" onchange="reRender()" /> Custom:
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb1" value="Programming" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Programming
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb2" value="Misc" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Misc
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb3" value="Dark" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Dark
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb4" value="Pun" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Pun
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb5" value="Spooky" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Spooky
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb6" value="Christmas" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Christmas
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               @* <span id="urlBuilderUrl">/Jokes/GetRequestURL</span>*@
                <button id="urlBuilderUrl" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">/Jokes/GetRequestURL</button>
            </div>
           
        </div>
        </form>
           
    <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered m-2">
        @if(Model != null)
        {
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var joke in Model)
            {
    <tr>
        <td>@joke.id</td>
        <td>@joke.type</td>
        <td>@joke.delivery</td>
        <td>@joke.flags</td>
        <td>@joke.joke</td>
       
    </tr>
    }
        </tbody>
        }
    </table>

   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Ajax `submit` to request the data.

```
@model Joke
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        var settings = {

            baseURL: "https://v2.jokeapi.dev",
            Endpoint: "joke",
            anyCategoryName: "Any",
        };
        var tryItURL = "";
        window.onload = function () { reRender(); };

        function reRender() {

            var isValid = false;
            document.getElementsByName("category").forEach(function (el) {
                if (!el.checked)
                    return;

                if (el.value == "Any") {
                    isValid = true;
                    ["cat-cb1", "cat-cb2", "cat-cb3", "cat-cb4", "cat-cb5", "cat-cb6"].forEach(function (cat) {
                        document.getElementById(cat).disabled = true;
                    });
                }
                else {
                    var isChecked = false;
                    ["cat-cb1", "cat-cb2", "cat-cb3", "cat-cb4", "cat-cb5", "cat-cb6"].forEach(function (cat) {
                        var cel = document.getElementById(cat);
                        cel.disabled = false;

                        if (cel.checked)
                            isChecked = true;
                    });

                    if (isChecked)
                        isValid = true;
                }
            });


            buildURL();

        }

        //#MARKER build URL
        function buildURL() {
            var queryParams = [];

            //#SECTION categories
            var selectedCategories = [settings.anyCategoryName];
            if (document.getElementById("Custom").checked) {
                selectedCategories = [];
                if (document.getElementById("cat-cb1").checked) {
                    selectedCategories.push("Programming");
                }
                if (document.getElementById("cat-cb2").checked) {
                    selectedCategories.push("Miscellaneous");
                }
                if (document.getElementById("cat-cb3").checked) {
                    selectedCategories.push("Dark");
                }
                if (document.getElementById("cat-cb4").checked) {
                    selectedCategories.push("Pun");
                }
                if (document.getElementById("cat-cb5").checked) {
                    selectedCategories.push("Spooky");
                }
                if (document.getElementById("cat-cb6").checked) {
                    selectedCategories.push("Christmas");
                }

                if (selectedCategories.length == 0) {
                    selectedCategories.push(settings.anyCategoryName);
                }
            }

            tryItURL = settings.baseURL + "/" + settings.Endpoint + "/" + selectedCategories.join(",");
           // tryItURL =  selectedCategories.join(",");
            if (queryParams.length > 0) {
                tryItURL += "?" + queryParams.join("&");
            }

            document.getElementById("urlBuilderUrl").innerText = tryItURL;
        }


        $(document).ready(function () {

            // process the form
            $('form').submit(function (event) {
                // process the form
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetRequestURL")", // the url where we want to POST
                    data: { newData: tryItURL }, // our data object
                    dataType: 'json' // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                })
                // using the done promise callback
                .done(function (data) {

                     // log data to the console so we can see
                    console.log(data);
                    document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = data.id;
                    document.getElementById('joke').innerHTML = data.joke;
                    document.getElementById('safe').innerHTML = data.safe;
                    document.getElementById('category').innerHTML = data.category;
                    document.getElementById('type').innerHTML = data.type;
                    document.getElementById('lang').innerHTML = data.lang;

                     // here we will handle errors and validation messages
                 });

                // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
                event.preventDefault();
            });

        });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="category" class="control-label"> Select category/categories</label>
            @*<input type="radio" value="Any" /> Any
                <input type="radio" value="Custom" name="Custom" /> Custom:*@

            <div><input type="radio" name="category" value="Any" checked="checked" id="Any" class="control-label" checked="checked" onchange="reRender()" /> Any</div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="category" value="Custom" class="control-label" id="Custom" onchange="reRender()" /> Custom:
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb1" value="Programming" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Programming
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb2" value="Misc" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Misc
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb3" value="Dark" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Dark
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb4" value="Pun" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Pun
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb5" value="Spooky" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Spooky
                <input type="checkbox" name="customcategory" id="cat-cb6" value="Christmas" class="control-label" onchange="reRender()" /> Christmas
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @* <span id="urlBuilderUrl">/Jokes/GetRequestURL</span>*@
                <button id="urlBuilderUrl" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">/Jokes/GetRequestURL</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>

    <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered m-2">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>id</td>
                <td id="id"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>joke</td>
                <td id="joke"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>safe</td>
                <td id="safe"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>category</td>
                <td id="category"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>type</td>
                <td id="type"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>lang</td>
                <td id="lang"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Test result
[image]

### Json Deserialize

From the links of https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Miscellaneous,Dark ,we can see it returns Joke object not list as you coded.

[image]

So define Joke like below:

```
public class Joke
{
    public bool error { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string joke { get; set; }
    public Flags flags { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string safe { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
}

public class Flags
{
    public bool nsfw { get; set; }
    public bool religious { get; set; }
    public bool political { get; set; }
    public bool racist { get; set; }
    public bool sexist { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("explicit")]
    public bool Explicit { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize successfully.

[image]

### Cors

Browser security prevents a web page from making requests to a different domain than the one that served the web page. This restriction is called the same-origin policy. The same-origin policy prevents a malicious site from reading sensitive data from another site. Sometimes, you might want to allow other sites to make cross-origin requests to your app.

When I tested your codes, I need to addCors to enable different domain request.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        app.UseCors(builder => builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());

        app.UseRouting();
        ...
    }
```

### View

When an action returns a `view`, a process called [**view discovery**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0#view-discovery) takes place. This process determines which view file is used based on the view name.

The default behavior of the `View` method (return `View()`;) is to return a view with the same name as the action method from which it's called. For example, the About `ActionResult` method name of the controller is used to search for a view file named About.cshtml. First, the runtime looks in the Views/[ControllerName] folder for the view. If it doesn't find a matching view there, it searches the Shared folder for the view.

It doesn't matter if you implicitly return the `ViewResult` with return `View()`; or explicitly pass the view name to the View method with return View("`<ViewName>`");
In both cases, view discovery searches for a matching view file in this order:

- Views/[ControllerName]/[ViewName].cshtml
- Views/Shared/[ViewName].cshtml

In your case, you could return a view and a model:

```
return View("Views/Joke/Index.cshtml", randomJoke);
```

if will search `Views/Jokes/Index.cshtml`.

[image]

Test result：
[image]

Comment: Hi @Michael Wang I don't think the view discovery is the issue here as I am using a view with the same name as the action method GetRequestURL() with the View name as GetRequestURL.cshtml and the view is within the Views/Jokes folder (Jokes being the controller name. Now will you please share your VS solution on GitHub or write the full action method/view as you have done before. Your displaying the response on POSTMAN is not helping. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, @krchome, you should first to locate the line of  the error in your action. In my codes, I didn't redirect with the list from HttpClient as you code. I test it with static list and that's why I got data in view.

Comment: 1. Have you send post request successfully via Ajax? 2. If yes, Does the action method recieve the string of newData? 3. If yes, Does it get list from the newData Url? 4. If yes, Does it deserialize object successfully？

Comment: Yes I did all that you have asked in your latest comment as 1. I have sent post request successfully via Ajax . 2. Yes the action method receives the string containing the URL (That's how I know the success of step 1 through attaching the breakpoint on the action method, right) 3. Yes it does get the serialized json response from the URL sent 4. Yes, it does deserialize the object successfully (as seen on mouseover when breakpoints are hit). The code is at : https://github.com/krchome/JokeAPIClient.git  (The only folder of importance is WebAPI Consume  and the solution file)

Comment: Great, I already updated about how to deserialize from the returning data of  https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any

Comment: Update your view @Model

Comment: Hi @Michael Wang, Following all your recommendations, I could successfully deserialize from the returning data of https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any  The problem however is that I am still not able to render it (deserialized joke object) on the view which was my original issue when I browse to my localhost URL: https://localhost:44398/Jokes/GetRequestURL  Could I explain myself clearly what I wanted with the solution, please let me know?

Comment: You have double submitted your form. You should use ajaxForm to request data. I will update the codes later.

Comment: Ok great. Shall be waiting for your valued response.

Comment: Already update for u. You could check the new way to update view via Ajax.

Comment: It's all going fine now with the view showing the data returned from server. Please note the only thing I needed to change was the return type of the action method to return Json(randomJoke)

Comment: I have accepted the solution. Thanks very much for your time, appreciate it.